# How to approach auto-updates in the background

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have

1. 1-many units in the database
2. Each unit has it's own update time in seconds
3. Webpage that has dynamic contents
4. Currently there is auto-refresh (2minutes) embedded see below every time it's called

`function refreshPage(){`

```
minutes = 2;
seconds = 0;  
interval=120000;
getCheckedUnits(); //call to function that checks and updates stuff
```

}

```
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    //refreshPage();
    setInterval(refreshPage, timeoutPeriod);
    countdown('countdown');
}

var interval;
var minutes = 2;
var seconds = 0;

function countdown(element) {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        var el = document.getElementById(element);
        if(seconds == 0) {
            if(minutes == 0) {
                el.innerHTML = "Waiting for refresh";
                clearInterval(interval);
                return;
            } else {
                minutes--;
                seconds = 60;
            }
        }
        if(minutes > 0) {
            var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
        } else {
            var minute_text = '';
        }
        var second_text = seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
        el.innerHTML = 'Page will auto-refresh in: ' + minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
        seconds--;
    }, 1000);
}
```

What I need to do, it to make it transparent to user and call update based on the need (I have value that is set in the database).

As a solution (in JS-Ajax), I can use the same timer that I have above (set it to 5 seconds) and create an array with objects that store id, last update time and next update time. Then I can update each object only when current time is more that next update time. 
Or I can approach this method via cron-job.

I have never done this before and I would like to hear opinions that based on experience. What would be the best option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scheme of fetching last update times and comparing them before fetching the much larger data is a perfectly valid approach to this problem, but there are others you can consider. In particular, you are trying to achieve is called [server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology). Using the last-update timestamps can approximate this, but alternative techniques like long polling and (in the future/some browsers) WebSockest are some alternatives.

[Here is a better writeup to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110550/is-there-a-real-server-push-over-http).